# How to avoid numerical overflow in log of absolute value of sum of cubes?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm interested to compute a quantity log(| sum_i [(x_i)^3] |); The problem of directly using `np.log(abs((x**3).sum()))` (where x is a array of elements, and x**3 is to apply cube function element wisely to the array) is that some values in `x**3` could be so large and has potential numerical issues.

My plan is to use `logsumexp` trick. However, the absolute value outside of the sum is hard to get rid of. Any help?

Comment: @pault could be as big as 7.92591409e+38 something which label as `inf` in `torch.float32`

Comment: Is that a value in `x` or the sum of the cubes? Can [edit] your question to include a [mcve], to remove ambiguity and give a benchmark? **Edit**: Please include a small sample `x` array.

Comment: @pault sorry for ambiguity, its sum of cubes. The direct implementation in `numpy` is `np.log(abs((x**3).sum()))` where `x` is a array of elements, and `x**3` is element wise cube

Comment: Hard to tell if it will work without some sample data, but you could try dividing by a large constant before the cube: `np.log(constant**3) + np.log(abs(((x/constant)**3).sum(0)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a little bit of math to avoid numerical overflow.

Suppose `x` is an `numpy` array.

The problem comes from the `abs((x**3).sum())`, specifically the cubing operation. We can make the computation more stable by scaling down each number in `x` by a constant. Because we are dividing by a constant inside the array *before* the cubing, we need to multiply by the constant cubed *outside* the summation.

In other words:

```
abs((x**3).sum()) = (constant**3)*abs(((x/constant)**3).sum())
```

Using properties of logs, you can simplify your final expression to the following:

```
np.log(constant**3) + np.log(abs(((x/constant)**3).sum(0)))
```

Comment: Hey I know this might be a late reply. If the current solution proposed can safely deal with the case when `x**3` is very positive large. But how do we deal with the case when `x**3` can be both very large (1e89) or very negative (-1e89). That is give a array of data `x` some `x[I]` can be very large and some `x[j]` can be very negative such that `x[j]**3` is `-inf`

Comment: You can save the sign of `x` and reapply it after (since `x**3` maintains the sign).